# NilClass# failed with TypeError: nil is not a symbol

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, actionmailer, delayed-job

I am unable to send emails. i have already tried the following: 
Converting type of handler from text to long text does'nt work as i am using postgres.
I have also tried restarting my workers and delayed jobs 
and my delayed job is  version is 3.0.1.

I am having problem on the line:

Notifier.delay.delivery_alert(u)

and my delivery_alert method is

```
def delivery_alert(user) 
    @user = user
    @deliveries = @user.issues.includes(:copy => [:rentable]).current.by_last_status("to_be_delivered").map(&:copy).map(&:rentable)
    @returns = @user.issues.includes(:copy => [:rentable]).current.by_last_status("marked_for_return").map(&:copy).map(&:rentable)
    mail(:to => @user.email)
end
```

While on localhost i am getting the error:

[Worker(host:ubuntu pid:12169)] Class#delivery_alert failed with NoMethodError: undefined method `delivery_alert' for # - 5 failed attempts
for which i have added a patch in my lib folder

```
require 'yaml'

module Delayed
 module Backend
  module Base
   def payload_object
    YAML::ENGINE.yamler = 'psych'
    @payload_object ||= YAML.load(self.handler)
    rescue TypeError, LoadError, NameError, ArgumentError => e
     raise DeserializationError,
     "Job failed to load: #{e.message}. Handler: #{handler.inspect}"
    end
   end
 end

 class PerformableMailer
  def perform
    double = object.is_a?( String ) ? object.constantize : object
    double.send(method_name, *args).deliver
  end
 end
end
```

by taking reference of

https://gist.github.com/oelmekki/2181381

but still my email are not going. Thanks in advance?

Comment: Does `Notifier.delivery_alert(u)` work?

Comment: Yes it seems to be the same issue, can you either downgrade to 2.x or upgrade to at least 3.0.5?

Comment: zrl3dx- I have tried upgrading delayed_jobs to 3.0.5 but still facing the NoMethodError on localhost.

Comment: require your notifier class (require 'notifier' # or the actual path) in script/delayed_job to see if it works. Seems delayed_job is not loading it automatically.